# duplicate key exception using Spring Boot + JPA Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-mongo

I get a duplicate key exception (see bottom) when saving an object in Mongo DB. However the code is pretty simple and it first tries to retrieve the object:

```
@Service
public class UsersPlayersService extends AbstractService {

    public UsersPlayers add(String firebaseId, UserPlayerDetails userPlayerDetails) {
        UsersPlayers usersPlayers = usersPlayersRepository.findByFirebaseId(firebaseId);
        if (usersPlayers == null) {
            usersPlayers = new UsersPlayers();
        }
        usersPlayers.setFirebaseId(firebaseId);
        Set<UserPlayerDetails> details = usersPlayers.getUserPlayerDetails();
        details.remove(userPlayerDetails);
        details.add(userPlayerDetails);
        return usersPlayersRepository.save(usersPlayers);
    }

}
```

Rest controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{firebaseId}/add") 
@ApiOperation(value = "Add user player details to existing user's players, create if it doesn't exist") 
public UsersPlayers add(
    @PathVariable("firebaseId") String firebaseId, 
    @RequestBody UserPlayerDetails userPlayerDetails) {

   return usersPlayersService.add(firebaseId, userPlayerDetails); 
}
```

My object looks like:

```
    class UsersPlayers {

        public UsersPlayers() {}

        @Id
        private ObjectId id;

        @JsonProperty
        @Indexed(unique = true)
        private String firebaseId;
...
```

And the error is:

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: fantisserie.UsersPlayers index:
 firebaseId dup key: { : "UWRQZJzLMVesBpwSVQywfBIgw5j2" }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E1100
0 duplicate key error collection: fantisserie.UsersPlayers index: firebaseId dup key: { : "UWRQZJzLMVesBpwSVQywfBIgw5
j2" }
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoException
Translator.java:101) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:
2793) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.11.RELEASE]
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong are greatly appreciated!

Comment: This service is called from `@RestController`? Maybe you are trying to save twice same `UsersPlayers`

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate? The rest Controller class calls the service layer: @PostMapping(value = "/{firebaseId}/add")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Add user player details to existing user's players, create if it doesn't exist")
    public UsersPlayers add(@PathVariable("firebaseId") String firebaseId, @RequestBody UserPlayerDetails userPlayerDetails) {
        return usersPlayersService.add(firebaseId, userPlayerDetails);
    }